# Why isnt my PHP code entering anything into a mysql database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

For some reason I cant send POST string values, or any values for that matter to my database, all the columns use varchar with correct lengths and im pretty sure im setting up the SQL query statements correctly. I've looked and found answered questions close to this but it still wont work and ive also ran it through a [PHP validator](http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/) multiple times with no syntax errors.

Below is my code:

**Apply.php**

```
<?php
$required = array('name', 'age', 'position', 'email', 'desc');
$name= $_POST["name"];
$age= $_POST["name"];
$email= $_POST["email"];
$position= $_POST["position"];
$desc= $_POST["desc"];
$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $error = true;
  }
}

if ($error) {
  echo "You must fill in all fields";
} 
else {
  echo "Application Submitted, You will receive an email with a validation code in 1-2 days </br>Ask the owner in game for faster service";
    mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","apply");
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO applications (name, age, email, position, desc) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$email', '$position', '$desc')");
    mysqli_close();
  }
?>
```

**read_database.php**

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="password";
$database="apply";
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM applications") ; 

echo "<table border='1'> 
<tr> 
<th> Name </th> 
<th> Age </th> 
<th> Email Address </th> 
<th> Position </th> 
<th> Reasoning </th> 
</tr>"; 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['desc'] . "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 

} 

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Check for an error from `mysql_query()`. If it returns `false`, print `mysql_error()` to see the error.

Comment: In the second script, you're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions. That won't work.

Comment: You do a MySQL no no. Check out this PHP documentation to increase the security of your script http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.  Also, when outputting arbitrary strings into HTML, be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` to be sure you're generating valid HTML, and avoiding folks inserting their own JavaScript into your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the manual for `mysqli_query` https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","apply");
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO applications (name, age, email, position, desc) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$email', '$position', '$desc')");
mysqli_close();
```

OR

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","apply");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO applications (name, age, email, position, desc) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$email', '$position', '$desc')");
mysqli_close();
```

Comment: Thank you this was indeed the issue as it tuns out becuase im new to php the origial code I modified did not have the comma between $link and the query and I deleted it assuming it was not needed.